# How to get GPS info of a phone without internet, using Ionic 2?

Tags: javascript, geolocation, gps, ionic2, google-geolocation

everyone!
I am developing Ionic App that tracking the positions.
Now I am using Geolocation plugin in Ionic 2.
But it works only when internet connected.
But I want to get the location info without Internet, from the phone GPS directly.
How can I do?

Comment: Can you put your code here?

Comment: Code exemple plz !